# Do gems generate constantly?

Tags: android, godus

While unearthing some gems veins in the game for later mining I realised that every time I log to the game the vein seems to "grow" larger. I tested flatting everything around the place where the line of the vein ends and the next time I log on gems  seems to go further in that place. Is this a bug (I am not seeing the gems even if they are there) or do they grow somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure if gems are meant to regenerate or not, but the earth/chests do shift a little bit each game.

I know this for sure because during one OCD session, I unveiled the corner of each treasure chest because I was close to getting stone-aged chests.  On subsequent game plays, the chests have been re-buried, sometimes underneath (!?) an abode and thus no longer reachable without destruction.

Comment: Thanks. It is not exactly htn, but I am thinking its a visual bug or somethig. While unearthing gem veins, I use to stop when I could not see more gems (i.e. i waas in the end of the vein). But while login in later, I could see that more gems were goingunder the montain and I needed to unearth more. I eeded to do this about 10 times to finish the vein